# ¿Cómo modificar mis pantallas dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla en android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Bueno actualmente estoy desarrollando una app en android studio pero me he enfocado en hacer que se vea bien en los celulares, pero he descuidado el que se vea de buena bien en dispositivos como tabletas o elementos que son mas amplios que un celular. Me gustaría saber de que manera puedo hacer que mi pantallas  ya sea ubicación de mis componentes cambie dependiendo de las dimensiones de el dispositivo en el cual se ha instalado la app.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar los nuevos calificadores creados a partir del OS 3.2 https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers o cargar un layout respectivo mediante setContentView().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para realizar esto precisamente se tienen los folders destinados para este proposito en donde se crean los layouts correspondientes, incluso los folders de imagenes destinados para la densidad correspondiente

Los directorios para layouts son :

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout para pantalla normal ("por defecto")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout para pantalla grande
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout para pantalla extra grande
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout para pantalla extragrande en orientacion landscape
```

**Para el caso de tablets desde Android 3.2 se agregaron nuevos calificadores**:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Donde puedes establecer una diferencia al cargar tu layout dependiendo de la densidad de pixeles, por ejemplo:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # para télefonos (mas pequeños que 600dp de ancho disponible)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp de ancho y mayores )
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # Para tablets de 10”  (720dp de ancho y mayores)
```

En cuanto a las imagenes, los directorios para imagenes son:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap para densidad media
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap para densidad grande
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap para densidad extra grande
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap para densidad extra extra grande

res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icono para densidad media
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icono para densidad grande
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icono para densidad extra grande
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icono para densidad extra extra grande
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icono para densidad extra extra extra grande
```

Para mayor información puedes revisar la documentacion:

[Providing Resources in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

---

Puedes también detectar si tu dispositivo es una tablet mediante el método sugerido por Google:

```
public static boolean esTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
    }
```

Y en base a esto cargar un layout que tengas definido dentro del directorio `res/layout` el cual contenga una distribución de elementos diferente.

La carga de este layout definido para tablet se realizaría mediante el método `setContentView()` al cargar tu Activity:

```
if(esTablet(getApplicationContext()){ //tablet
     setContentView(R.layout.mi_layout_tablet);
}else{ // telefono
     setContentView(R.layout.mi_layout);
}
```

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, de esta forma haces que tu aplicación sea prácticamente compatible para todo tipo de dispositivos y tamaños

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear diferentes layouts dependiendo del **tamaño** del dispositivo:

> **small**    Recursos para pantallas de tamaño pequeño.
>
> **normal** Recursos para pantallas de tamaño normal. (Este es el tamaño de referencia).
>
> **large**    Recursos para pantallas de tamaño grande .
>
> **xlarge**    Recursos parapantallas de tamaño extragrande.

Si por ejemplo quieres crear un diseño para las tablets debes crear una carpeta que se llame `layout-large` o `layout-xlarge`:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml    
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml     
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml
```

Te recomiendo que te leas esta documentación:

[Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Providing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)