# Adaptación de Layout de App para todos los móviles

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy intentando adaptar mi *APP* a cualquier móvil.
Tengo algo claro, crear las siguientes carpetas:

```
layout-mdpi
layout-hdpi
layout-xhdpi
layout-xxhdpi
```

Y todo va perfectamente, pero que ocurre cuando un móvil `xxhdpi` tiene diferente DPI que todo se ve desordenado.

Un ejemplo

*Móvil >* `xxhdpi` *>* *560 DPI*

*Móvil >* `xxhdpi` *> 480 DPI*

¿Cómo se hace para tener otro `layout` para esas cosas? algo así como **`layout-xxhdpi-560dpi`** y que funcione en los `xxhdpi` de `560dpi` y así sucesivamente

EJEMPLOS:

XXHDPI - 560DPI

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

XXHDPI - 320DPI

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola UserNameYo, ¿Podrías ser mas específico? Sería perfecto si colocas una imagen con el estado actual y otra con el resultado esperado.

Comment: @x4mp73r dejo un ejemplo en el primer comentario, como podrás apreciar deja espacios distintos. Mi idea es que en cualquier DPI todo esté ordenado de la misma forma

Comment: Seria bueno que subieras tu layout, para ver la forma en la que lo creaste

Comment: **Se tiene una pregunta similar en el sitio** : http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34068/c%C3%B3mo-modificar-mis-estilos-dependiendo-del-tama%C3%B1o-de-la-pantalla-en-android/34095#34095

Comment: Veo bien la imagen, pero noto que hay problemas con el tamaño del texto... ¿tendra la fuente aumentada o reducida la configuracion del smartphone? quizás puedas usar texto autoajustable https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías revisar la documentación donde expone lo que deseas:

**[Providing Resources in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)**

**[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html)**

Existen varias preguntas similares para realizar esto precisamente se tienen los folders destinados para este propósito en donde se crean los layouts correspondientes, incluso los folders de imágenes destinados para la densidad correspondiente:

Los directorios para layouts son :

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout para pantalla normal ("por defecto")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout para pantalla grande
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout para pantalla extra grande
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout para pantalla extragrande en orientacion landscape
```

**Para el caso de tablets desde Android 3.2 se agregaron nuevos calificadores**:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Donde puedes establecer una diferencia al cargar tu layout dependiendo de la densidad de pixeles, por ejemplo:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # para télefonos (mas pequeños que 600dp de ancho disponible)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp de ancho y mayores )
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # Para tablets de 10”  (720dp de ancho y mayores)
```

---

En cuanto a las imágenes, los directorios para imágenes son:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap para densidad media
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap para densidad grande
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap para densidad extra grande
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap para densidad extra extra grande

res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icono para densidad media
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icono para densidad grande
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icono para densidad extra grande
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icono para densidad extra extra grande
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icono para densidad extra extra extra grande
```

Answer (score 1):

Se deben manejar diferentes carpetas de layout segun el tamaño del layout siendo la nombre layout la carpeta por defecto para el que no tenga una medida especifica de resto se manejan layout-small layout-large etc.

Mira el siguiente link para tener detalle

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Ya lo probé y no me funcionó, por ejemplo: Como pongo para XXHDPI con 560DPI y otra para XXHDPI con 320DPI

Comment: prueba algo asi res/layout/main_activity.xml   #normales        
res/layout-sw550dp/main_activity.xml  #la resolucion que tiene problemas

Comment: Nada, da igual la DPI que le ponga, que no reconoce ese layout @Lcop

Comment: @UserNameYo que tamaño de imagen esta usando para las pantallas?

Answer (score -1):

no has pensado que tal vez el problema no sea el `layout` si no los componentes, por ejemplo si usas una imagen que no no esta en `hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdip, xxxhdip)`. es decir si solo tienes la imagen en `xxhdip` usara esa resolución en todas las pantallas y no se adaptara a ella dependiendo de su densidad. La verdad esto de las pantallas siempre sera un problema :p jaja

Comment: Siempre coge las imágenes de xxhdpi, da igual la DPI que le ponga, si que es un quebradero de cabeza esto, llevo dos y no doy con una solución.

Comment: pero las imágenes (iconos) yo las guardo en la misma carpeta donde cambias el icono de tu app(mimap), y la verdad no tengo problemas por ejemplo yo ejecuto las app en un s6 y el icono se me adapta. Y este icono lo descargo desde la pagina oficial de google, donde puedes selecionar si el icono por defecto sera de 24dp 0 32dp 0 48dp.

Comment: Yo el problema lo tengo con las DPI

Comment: Pero es obligatorio incorporar esa densidad si no ya como último opción sería limitar a ciertas densidades tu app